# passing a variable from jade to javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to pass a variable from the route handler to the javascript file.

express route that fetches home page is:

```
exports.home = function(req, res){

    var _ajaxData = [ ["#collections","collections", "Collections"],
                      ["#candidates","candidates", "Candidates"],
                      ["#entries","entriess", "Entries"],
                      ["#exits","exits", "Exits"]
                    ];

    res.render('home/home', { title: 'Welcome to My Web', _ajaxData: _ajaxData});
};
```

And my jade file looks like the following:

```
extends ../layout/base

block content
      each item in _ajaxData
        div(id= item[0]).col-md-6
              h3.panel-title= title
            .panel-body
              | Loading content...

  script(src='js/home.js')
```

And the content is loaded using ajax in home.js that looks like the following:

```
var ajaxData = JSON.stringify('!{_ajaxData}');
console.log(ajaxData);
// Further processing here
```

Problem: The console prints:

```
"!{_ajaxData}"
```

where I am looking to get the full array passed to the javascript.

Appreciate any insights

Comment: FYI: I realized that browser is fetching the home.js without any processing by express. However, I am still curious to know if there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this to your jade file

```
script(type='text/javascript')                                                   
  var local_data =!{JSON.stringify(data)};   
script(src='javascripts/myScript.js')
```

All your data should now be in `local_data` for your use in `myScript.js`

Comment: thanks worked with minor change: `script(type='text/javascript')                                                   
  | var local_data =!{JSON.stringify(data)};   
script(src='javascripts/myScript.js') `

Comment: otherwise, its turning var into <var>

Comment: You should add `.` character after the script e.g. `script(type='text/javascript').` so that you code is treated as text and not more templating

Comment: Jonathan is correct, for reference this changed recently. In older versions jade would understand that anything nested inside a `script` tag was a js block and not more templating; in recent versions (post 1.0.0 from memory) you need the trailing dot, or the pipe character.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :)